# Weird behaviour when searching for char in array string elements

Tags: php, string, strpos, strcmp, strstr

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', '-1');
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('apc.enabled', '0');
gc_enable();

$array = array("php", "php_php", "php_php", "php_php", "php");
$arraysize = count($array);
$style = " style='border: 1px solid black;'";
$strcmpcharcount = 0;
$equalcmpcharcount = 0;

foreach ($array as $key)
{
  $strcmpcharcount = 0;
  $equalcmpcharcount = 0;

  if (strstr($key, "_") !== false)
  {
    $strstr[] = "found";
    $explodedstring1[] = explode("_", $key);
  }
  else
  {
    $strstr[] = "not found";
    $explodedstring1[] = "not found";
  }

  if (strpos($key, "_") !== false)
  {
    $strpos[] = "found";
    $explodedstring2[] = explode("_", $key);
  }
  else
  {
    $strpos[] = "not found";
    $explodedstring2[] = "not found";
  }

  if (preg_match("/[^_+$]/", $key))
  {
    $preg_match[] = "found";
    $explodedstring3[] = explode("_", $key);
  }
  else
  {
    $preg_match[] = "not found";
    $explodedstring3[] = "not found";
  }

  $keysize = strlen($key);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $keysize; $i++)
  {
    if (strcmp($key[$i], "_") === 0) { $strcmpcharcount++; }
  }

  for ($j = 0; $j < $keysize; $j++)
  {
    if ($key[$j] === "_") { $equalcmpcharcount++; }
  }

  if ($strcmpcharcount > 0)
  {
    $strcmp[] = "found";
    $explodedstring4[] = explode("_", $key);
  }
  else
  {
    $strcmp[] = "not found";
    $explodedstring4[] = "not found";
  }

  if ($equalcmpcharcount > 0)
  {
    $equalcmp[] = "found";
    $explodedstring5[] = explode("_", $key);
  }
  else
  {
    $equalcmp[] = "not found";
    $explodedstring5[] = "not found";
  }
}
echo "<table$style>
<th$style>
<tr>
<td$style>strstr()</td>
<td$style>strpos()</td>
<td$style>preg_match()</td>
<td$style>strcmp()</td>
<td$style>'==='</td>
</tr>
</th>";
for($k = 0; $k < $arraysize; $k++)
{
  echo "<tr>
  <td$style>$strstr[$k]</td>
  <td$style>$strpos[$k]</td>
  <td$style>$preg_match[$k]</td>
  <td$style>$strcmp[$k]</td>
  <td$style>$equalcmp[$k]</td>
  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

exit();

?>
```

The problem is with first two functions - they randomly fails to find the underscore char. In fact I called more than 50 times the script to got proper results. Added and preg_match() test but just to know I'm not sure if it has valid regex.

Comment: When I run it the first two columns are always correct.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Stack is Debian+PHP 5.4.9+lighty and from 1000 iterations I've got more 'not found' than 'found'

Answer (score 0):

You're adding new elements to `$strstr`, `$strpos` tables and so on and in the end you do `for...` and printing from these tables where `$k` keys don't necessarily have to exists.

Check `var_dump` or `print_r` on these tables and you will see that in fact they got elements, but their indexes aren't matched with `$array` indexes (and i guess that's what you want to achieve).

You can change `foreach ($array as $key)` to `foreach ($array as $index => $key)` and all occurences like `$strstr[] = "found";` to `$strstr[$index] = "found";` (also for other recognision methods) and then run the script again to see results.

In last block (`for($k = 0; $k < $arraysize; $k++)...`) you should either validate if `$strstr[$k]` (and other arrays) exists before printing it, or print these arrays separately by `foreach`.

You can also make one table for results and make it multidimensional with function names as keys in the first level and put results in there.

Comment: Well, there's no reason to valide if $[k] isset for simple case, I'm just counting and matching each one of chars against "_". And no, I'm not adding new elements, that's why I'm printing in 'table' variant to be more clear, print_r and var_dump funcs show the same results.
Arrays exist, the problem is `with first two functions`, failing to return true in random intervals with the almost the SAME strings like in the array.